# webpack 'import' only at the top level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm trying to implement async routing in my react-project using [react-router-async-routing](https://github.com/zackify/react-router-async-routing).

The problem is that I get this error during webpack compiling:

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

It happens in my *router.js* which is equal to the one from the link above.
Replacing the `import` with `System.import` compiles without errors and the browser loads the chunk (visible in the **network-traffic-view**), but the page remains blank (I guess it is not being executed!).

This is my webpack-config:

```js
var { path, resolve } = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    app: "./src/js/user/main.js",
    vendor: ["react", "react-dom"]
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/resources/user/js",
    publicPath: "/resources/user/js/",
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js"
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      filename: "vendor.bundle.js"
    })
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /.(js|jsx)?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['env', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(less)$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        loader: "file-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: "url-loader"
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "global": __dirname + "/src/js/user/module/global"
    }
  }
};
```

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT1:

File with error:

```
import AsyncSetup from "react-router-async-routing";

import routes from "./routes";

const {Route, Link, Preload} = AsyncSetup(routes, path => {
    import(`./routes/${path}.jsx`);
});

export {Link, Route, Preload};
```

EDIT2:
I solved the problem with the import by installing

> babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

and adding it to babel :

```
test : /.(js|jsx)?$/,
loader: 'babel-loader',
exclude: /node_modules/,
query: {
    presets: [['es2015'], 'react'],
    plugins: ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

Now everything is working!

Comment: Please, share the file with the error as well as the `babelrc` file, there's not enough information for us to help you.

Comment: where can i find the babelrc file?

Comment: There should be a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project.

Comment: there is no babelrc file in my root (hidden files are shown)

Comment: Well, you are defining the babel configurations directly on the Webpack as I understood, that should work, no problem. In my projects I prefer to put in this configuration file, the IDE doesn't recognize when the file is not there.

Answer (score 1):

The new Import API is still a little confusing, because of different Node versions, and specially when using transpiling tools such as Babel and Webpack. I strongly recommend you to use `require()` instead of `import()` in your dynamic imports (where the file path is not a constant) and let `import` for constant dependencies, that's what I do in my projects, and I have no issues.

Something like this:

```
import AsyncSetup from "react-router-async-routing";

import routes from "./routes";

const {Route, Link, Preload} = AsyncSetup(routes, path => {
  return require(`./routes/${path}.jsx`);
});

export {Link, Route, Preload};
```

You can also use absolute paths, this might be safer depending on your environment and code.

```
import path from 'path';
import AsyncSetup from "react-router-async-routing";

import routes from "./routes";

const {Route, Link, Preload} = AsyncSetup(routes, path => {
  return require(path.join(__dirname, `./routes/${path}.jsx`));
});

export {Link, Route, Preload};
```

If this don't solve your issue, maybe you'll need to do some tweaking in the babel/webpack modules resolver.

Comment: Doesn't work!Is there any other way to do async routing in react (v15)?

Comment: This should work, as far as I know. Are you sure the paths are correct? You may also use absolute paths. I edited the answer for using them.

Comment: Actually, I was missing the "return" inside the arrow function, also updated my answer to reflect this.